# Which one is good Image processing language?

Tags: image-processing, optical-char-recognition

For my academic project, I need to process image to get pixel color and also needs to change the pixel color.I need pattern recognition. It is a web application. All I am trying is to capture the image of debit card by webcam and read the details. Please suggest me programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am using [Opencv](http://opencv.org/), you can program in it with C++ and Python, for example.

Comment: sir please tell me will opencv allow me to integrate it to the web development?

Comment: Yes. OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision Library) is usually accessed by other programs so they can use it's features. You can use it in Qt, Visual Studio ... it's very easy to set up everything.

Answer (score 0):

This question is much subjective in sense that *"how familiar you is with computers programming?"* or *"how much is your knowledge about programming and your pratices?".*
Commonly, some researchers have adopted MATLAB for prototype projects and after implements this project in a programming language like Java, C++, C.

In this time, some researchs have adopted Python and your modules for scientific computation.

So, what is the best way to getting started?

The fist thing that you should be in mind is: both languages are scripted programming languages.

The second one is: the Math Work's software , MATLAB, is a comercial software and you can get prices [here](http://www.mathworks.com).

The third is: Python is an open-source project, besides this uses the concept of object oriented programming. All infortmation about license and scipy ecossystem is found [here](http://www.scipy.org)

A simple example for the question in the context of practical programming is a for loop.

- Python using numpy module

`import numpy as np`
`a = np.ndarray([1, 2, 3])`

`for i in a-1
     print a[i]`

- MATLAB

`a = [1, 2, 3];`

`for i = 1:length(a)
    disp(a(i))`

`end`

To develop in these programming languages ,  the initital skill that you should have is undestand arrays in depth.

To know about slicing, dimensions and all the operations that you can do with arrays, is highly recommend check the user guide of the languages.

Thanks to comunity both languages have a great active comunity, and you can get help easily.

The question *"How to choose?"* is answered with another question *" What language is comfortable to you?"*

Comment: Sir I heard that matlab is difficult to integrate with web application.Is it true? if not please tell a way of doing so. I need to read debit card details from debit card image.